# html button to send email

Tags: html, forms, email

How do I send an email with specified initial values for the headers `subject` and `message` from a button in html, such as this

```
<form method="post" action="mailto:email.com?subject=subject&message=message">
```

where `subject` and `message` are values fetched from a `form`?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

You can use `mailto`, here is the HTML code:

```
<a href="mailto:EMAILADDRESS">
```

Replace `EMAILADDRESS` with your email.

Answer (score 43):

This method doesn't seem to work in my browser, and looking around indicates that the whole subject of specifying headers to a `mailto` link/action is sparsely supported, but maybe this can help...

HTML:

```
<form id="fr1">
    <input type="text" id="tb1" />
    <input type="text" id="tb2" />
    <input type="button" id="bt1" value="click" />
</form>
```

JavaScript (with jQuery):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#bt1').click(function() {
        $('#fr1').attr('action',
                       'mailto:test@test.com?subject=' +
                       $('#tb1').val() + '&body=' + $('#tb2').val());
        $('#fr1').submit();
    });
});
```

Notice what I'm doing here.  The form itself has no action associated with it.  And the submit button isn't really a `submit` type, it's just a `button` type.  Using JavaScript, I'm binding to that button's click event, setting the form's action attribute, and then submitting the form.

It's working in so much as it submits the form to a `mailto` action (my default mail program pops up and opens a new message to the specified address), but for me (Safari, Mail.app) it's not actually specifying the Subject or Body in the resulting message.

HTML isn't really a very good medium for doing this, as I'm sure others are pointing out while I type this.  It's possible that this may work in some browsers and/or some mail clients.  However, it's really not even a safe assumption anymore that users will have a fat mail client these days.  I can't remember the last time I opened mine.  HTML's `mailto` is a bit of legacy functionality and, these days, it's really just as well that you perform the mail action on the server-side if possible.

Comment: Pretty shocked at the accepted answer here, when you and others have put such effort into explaining this very well :(

Comment: @Madmartigan: Indeed. I thought the comment thread you had going with the OP was pretty enlightening.  The accepted answer seemed... unhelpful.  In fact, I nearly commented on it asking how just moving the _exact_ action from a form action to an anchor is supposed to help with the subject/body issue in the question.  Oh well.

Comment: FWIW, a lot of my clients really love mailto links on their sites, even though they are clunky, but they are the folks who use default Microsoft tools for everything at work (including default mail program) and send me emails as .doc attachments haha

Comment: Well, voting seems to have taken care of that. For a minute I thought this *was* the accepted answer. :)

Comment: As I write in [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29975611/2450941), this suggestion does not fulfill the OP's request, which is an email _with subject and message_. Also, David's solution doesn't work because most, maybe all, combinations of browsers plus e-mail clients do not accept the subject and body attributes of the mailto: URI when supplied as a <form>'s action. Rather, use <a> styled as a button.

Answer (score 12):

As David [notes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5773291/2450941), his suggestion does not actually fulfill the OP's request, which was an email *with subject and message*. It doesn't work because most, maybe all, combinations of browsers plus e-mail clients do not accept the `subject` and `body` attributes of the `mailto:` URI when supplied as a `<form>`'s `action`.

But here's a working example:

HTML (with [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/) styles):

```
<p><input id="subject" type="text" placeholder="type your subject here" 
    class="form-control"></p>
<p><input id="message" type="text" placeholder="type your message here" 
    class="form-control"></p>
<p><a id="mail-link" class="btn btn-primary">Create email</a></p>
```

JavaScript (with [jQuery](https://jquery.com/)):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function loadEvents() {
        var mailString;
        function updateMailString() {
            mailString = '?subject=' + encodeURIComponent($('#subject').val())
                + '&body=' + encodeURIComponent($('#message').val());
            $('#mail-link').attr('href',  'mailto:person@email.com' + mailString);
        }
        $( "#subject" ).focusout(function() { updateMailString(); });
        $( "#message" ).focusout(function() { updateMailString(); });
        updateMailString();
    }
</script>
```

Notes:

- The `<form>` element with associated `action` attribute is not used.
- The `<input>` element of type `button` is also not used.

  - `<a>` styled as a button (here using Bootstrap) replaces `<input type="button">`
  - `focusout()` with `updateMailString()` is necessary because the `<a>` tag's `href` attribute does not automatically update when the input fields' values change.
  - `updateMailString()` is also called when document is loaded in case the input fields are prepopulated.
- Also `encodeURIComponent()` is used to get characters such as the quotation mark (") across to Outlook.

In this approach, the `mailto:` URI is supplied (with `subject` and `body` attributes) in an `a` element's `href` tag. This works in all combinations of browsers and e-mail clients I have tested, which are recent (2015) versions of:

- **Browsers:** Firefox/Win&OSX, Chrome/Win&OSX, IE/Win, Safari/OSX&iOS, Opera/OSX
- **E-mail clients:** Outlook/Win, Mail.app/OSX&iOS, Sparrow/OSX

Bonus tip: In my use cases, I add some contextual text to the e-mail `body`. More often than not, I want that text to contain line breaks. `%0D%0A` (carriage return and linefeed) works in my tests.

Answer (score 6):

I couldn't ever find an answer that really satisfied the original question, so I put together a simple free service ([PostMail](https://postmail.invotes.com)) that allows you to make a standard HTTP POST request to send an email. When you sign up, it provides you with code that you can copy & paste into your website. In this case, you can simply use a form post:

HTML:

```
<form action="https://postmail.invotes.com/send"
    method="post" id="email_form">

    <input type="text" name="subject" placeholder="Subject" />
    <textarea name="text" placeholder="Message"></textarea>
    <!-- replace value with your access token -->
    <input type="hidden" name="access_token" value="{your access token}" />

    <input type="hidden" name="success_url"
      value=".?message=Email+Successfully+Sent%21&isError=0" />
    <input type="hidden" name="error_url"
      value=".?message=Email+could+not+be+sent.&isError=1" />

    <input id="submit_form" type="submit" value="Send" />
</form>
```

Again, in full disclosure, I created this service because I could not find a suitable answer.

Comment: I use this piece of code but clicking send button does nothing.
Have you managed to send e-mail?

Comment: Did you enter your email on https://postmail.invotes.com? You have to do that first, then replace {your access token} with the one that is sent to your inbox.

Comment: Yes, I did. App loads perfectly, net after clicking sending button nothing happens. App do no load anything. You can click send button any times you want and anything happens. I used your code with my own token

Comment: I've updated the example by adding the success_url and error_url parameters: <input type="hidden" name="success_url"
          value=".?message=Email+Successfully+Sent%21&isError=0" />
        <input type="hidden" name="error_url"
          value=".?message=Email+could+not+be+sent.&isError=1" /> This should cause the page to redirect back to your website. Does that help?

Answer (score 3):

You can not directly send an email with a HTML form. You can however send the form to your web server and then generate the email with a server side program written in e.g. PHP.

The other solution is to create a link as you did with the "mailto:". This will open the local email program from the user. And he/she can then send the pre-populated email.

When you decided how you wanted to do it you can ask another (more specific) question on this site. (Or you can search for a solution somewhere on the internet.)

Answer (score 3):

@user544079

Even though it is very old and irrelevant now, I am replying to help people like me! 
it should be like this:

```
<form method="post" action="mailto:$emailID?subject=$MySubject &message= $MyMessageText">
```

Here 
$emailID, 
$MySubject, 
$MyMessageText are variables which you assign from a FORM or a DATABASE Table or just you can assign values in your code itself. Alternatively you can put the code like this (normally it is not used):

`<form method="post" action="mailto:admin@website.com?subject=New Registration Alert &message= New Registration requires your approval">`

Answer (score 2):

You can use an anchor to attempt to open the user's default mail client, prepopulated, with `mailto:`, but you cannot send the actual email. *Apparently it is possible to do this with a form action as well, but browser support is varied and unreliable, so I do not suggest it.

HTML cannot send mail, you need to use a server side language like php, which is another topic. There are plently of good resources on how to do this here on SO or elsewhere on the internet.

If you are using php, I see [SwiftMailer](http://swiftmailer.org/) suggested quite a bit.

Comment: Some browsers, at least at some point, did actually support forms with mailto actions. They would send the data as an URL encoded message to the provided address. There was even software to decode forms directly from the mailbox and view them. I haven't seen any such forms for a decade, though, since sending mail from the server side is just so much better.

Comment: @Matti Virkkunen: That is interesting, I never knew that. Which browsers supported this feature? I see some mention of it [here](http://apptools.com/rants/mailto.php).

Comment: Presumably at least old version of IE. In fact, I tried one such form in my current version of Chromium and it tried to launch a mail client (I don't have one installed on this computer though), so at least they still do something. I don't know if the data had gone through, though.

Comment: I just tried in FF and it opened my MS Outlook (which is not configured), populated with some of the form values and the subject "Form Post From Mozilla". Interesting.

Answer (score 0):

```
 <form action="mailto:someone@example.com" method="post"               enctype="text/plain">
 Name:<br>
<input type="text" name="name"><br>
 E-mail:<br>
<input type="text" name="mail"><br>
Comment:<br>
<input type="text" name="comment" size="50"><br><br>
<input type="submit" value="Send">
<input type="reset" value="Reset">
```