# Can you send an email from an (HTML) RMarkdown Document?

Tags: r, automation, r-markdown, dt

I want to be clear and mention I am not trying to email out my RMarkdown document. What I am trying to do is the following, say I email an RMarkdown document to a user, can they then email someone within the HTML document with specific data points they are interested in. I'll elaborate below:

Say my recipient finds these rows of data interesting, can the user select these rows of data and then email someone at the click of a button within the document. I am using the DT package to create a CSV button and table within my document

[image]

Comment: This [seems possible](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5773291/13513328) with javascript, the link between `DT` and `mailto:` remains to be implemented

Comment: If you could add shiny, there is a [Bookmarking](https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/bookmarking-state.html) functionality in Shiny, where you can edit the document, and then get a URL of the app in that specific state(with data points they are interested in)