# How to create a button that let you send a email

Tags: html, html-email, contact-form

I'm trying to create a button that once you click on it, it lets you send an email to the email you add to the code, I tried "mailto" but its not working. Here the code:

```html
<div class="col-12 col-md-6 col-lg-3 grid-margin">
  <h5 class="pb-2">Contáctanos</h5>
  <p class="text-muted">Para más información, envíanos un correo!</p>
  <form>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Email" placeholder="Email">
  </form>
  <div class="pt-3">
    <button class="btn btn-dark">Subscribirse <a href="mailto:info@epce.edu.pe"></a></button>
  </div>
</div>
```

I'll be waiting for your help, thanks!

Comment: Is the form within an email, or on a web page?

Comment: You can check below link-
[RelatedStackOverFlowAnswerLink](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5773174/html-button-to-send-email)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [html button to send email](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5773174/html-button-to-send-email)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this, **it still uses mailto but in javascript** which doesnt cause errors:

```
    <div class="col-12 col-md-6 col-lg-3 grid-margin">
        <h5 class="pb-2">Contáctanos</h5>
        <p class="text-muted">Para más información, envíanos un correo!</p>
        <form>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Email" placeholder="Email">
        </form>
        <div class="pt-3">
          <button  onclick=send_email() class="btn btn-dark">Subscribirse <a href="mailto:info@epce.edu.pe"></a></button>
        </div>
      </div>
    
    <script>
    function send_email() {
    //get the input
    user_email = document.getElementById("Email");
    //use mailto:
    location.href = "mailto:" + user_email.value;
    }
    </script>
```